# Get all comments

Tags: comments

How do I get all the comments posted for a node? The REST API seems not to return them in a usable manner.

```
    {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/node/3?_format=hal_json"
    },
    "type": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/type/node/article"
    },
    "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/relation/node/article/uid": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/user/1?_format=hal_json",
        "lang": "en"
      }
    ],
    "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/relation/node/article/revision_uid": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/user/1?_format=hal_json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "uuid": [
    {
      "value": "5326216b-0e65-454b-8a48-720b6e6e2402"
    }
  ],
  "type": [
    {
      "target_id": "article"
    }
  ],
  "langcode": [
    {
      "value": "en",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "title": [
    {
      "value": "Testing Post Article",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "_embedded": {
    "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/relation/node/article/uid": [
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/user/1?_format=hal_json"
          },
          "type": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/type/user/user"
          }
        },
        "uuid": [
          {
            "value": "e7f777b9-8bd7-4f87-a100-d1784d6ed1bc"
          }
        ],
        "lang": "en"
      }
    ],
    "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/relation/node/article/revision_uid": [
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/user/1?_format=hal_json"
          },
          "type": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/drupal8/rest/type/user/user"
          }
        },
        "uuid": [
          {
            "value": "e7f777b9-8bd7-4f87-a100-d1784d6ed1bc"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": [
    {
      "value": "1",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "created": [
    {
      "value": "1490939860",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "changed": [
    {
      "value": "1490939860",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "promote": [
    {
      "value": "1",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "sticky": [
    {
      "value": "0",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "revision_timestamp": [
    {
      "value": "1490939860"
    }
  ],
  "revision_translation_affected": [
    {
      "value": "1",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "default_langcode": [
    {
      "value": "1",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "body": [
    {
      "value": "article",
      "format": null,
      "summary": null,
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "comment": [
    **{
      "status": "2",
      "cid": "3",
      "last_comment_timestamp": "1490944700",
      "last_comment_name": "",
      "last_comment_uid": "1",
      "comment_count": "2",
      "lang": "en"
    }**
  ]
}
```

As can be seen it gives a count but not the Ids of the Comments..

I am using **Drupal 8.0.2**

Comment: Hey, what's your reason for not upgrading your Drupal core, REST has come a long way since 8.0.2? Maybe there's something useful in the docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution.

1. Create a view with rest export with below settings.
   VIEW SETTINGS: show = **comments** and type = **all**
2. After view is created the change the **entity** with **fields** in format settings
3. Then add the required fields in view, also select content type field so that you can differenciate between comments.
4. Add contexual filter with **id**, add change path with **{yourpath}/%**
5. Check output on Postman or any other app.

This is working for me,and becuase of this I can able to get the comments related to individual content.

If you want comment related to article content type then you can add the filter criteria.

Hope this will work for you!